# Why are custom Fiori apps are opened within iframe in Fiori launchpad?

Tags: sapui5

- Standard Fiori apps does not indulge opening in `iframe`, they are enclosed within `div` tag. What is the
  reason?
- Does it have any advantages or disadvantages?

> Couldn't find any blogs regarding this. Can someone explain in
>   brief about this.

Comment: Are you using LPD_CUST to configure this custom app?

Comment: yes LPD_CUST only

Comment: Probably that’s why. You should consider not using LPD CUST and use Fiori Launchpad Designer to the embed your UI5 app using he proper setting in target mapping. LPD CUST is only needed in old versions.